# Perl: Constructing simple regular expression during runtime

Tags: regex, perl, runtime

I am trying to construct a small regex during runtime, but somehow it never matches -- what am I doing wrong?

```
my $word = quotemeta("test");
my $lines = "just a test to testing find tester testönig something fastest out pentest";

my $rule = "m/" . $word . "/g";
my $regex = qr/$rule/;

while ($lines =~ $regex) {
    # this never happens...
    print "\nFound pattern: '$&'";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
my $word = quotemeta("test");
my $rule = "m/" . $word . "/g";
my $regex = qr/$rule/;
```

is the same as this:

```
my $word = quotemeta("test");
my $rule = "m/test/g";     # interpolated $word
my $regex = qr~m/test/g~;  # interpolated $rule
```

That is, it matches the literal string "`m/test/g`" and nothing else.

[buff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328977/buff) has already given pretty much the same code I would have suggested, except that I recommend avoiding the use of `$&` due to a performance penalty as noted in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable
>   performance penalty on all regular expression matches. To avoid this
>   penalty, you can extract the same substring by using `@-`. Starting with
>   Perl v5.10.0, you can use the `/p` match flag and the `${^MATCH}` variable
>   to do the same thing for particular match operations.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $word = quotemeta("test");
my $lines = "just a test to testing find tester testönig something fastest out pentest";

my $regex = qr/$word/;

while ($lines =~ /$regex/g) {
    print "\nFound pattern: '$&'";
}
```

You cannot use `/g` directly with `qr`.

Comment: @user1769925 This is the correct answer.  However it's worth noting that using `qr//` gives no performance increase in this setup.  That's because while the regex is parsed and assigned to `$regex`, it is interpolated and reparsed in `//g`.  I would therefore remove the `qr//` assignment as wasted effort.